# PreventDefault event not working in Backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, backbone.js

I'm learning Backbone.js from lightweight django and i'm unable to get the below function from triggering a default event.

the below is my html for the button

```
<script type="text/html" id="header-template">
    <span class="title">Scrum Board Example</span>
    <% if (authenticated ) { %>
        <nav>
            <a href="/" class="button">Your Sprints</a>
            <a href="#" class="logout">Logout</a>
        </nav>
    <% } %>
</script>
```

and this is my backbone view

```
var HeaderView = TemplateView.extend({
    tagName: 'header',
    templateName: '#header-template',
    events: {
        'click a.logout': 'logout'
    },
    getContext: function () {
        return {authenticated: app.session.authenticated()};
    },
    logout: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('clicked');
        app.session.delete();
        window.location = '/';
    }
});
```

whenever I click on the a href button - it doesn’t seem to be triggering the logout function in my view model.

Am i going wrong somewhere else?

Thanks,.
KJ

Comment: so it does not even log "clicked"?

Comment: no - it reloads the page to localhost:8000/#

Comment: have you tried `return false` at the end of the function instead of `event.preventDefault`?

Comment: tried that right now - doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: i changed window.location to '/#' and the function seems to activate - any idea why this happens? im still unable to logout though

Comment: `window.location = '/'` reloads the page immediately. Do you want the page to reload after logging out?

Comment: How do you create and render the view ? can you show this part of code ?

Comment: What about to ask the same question than Anonymous0Day, how do you create and render the view ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use preventDefault() there is no reason to use href.

```
<a class="button">Your Sprints</a>
```

But if you use window.location = '/' why using preventDefault.

Also using a callback for your delete function could be cool.

```
var callback = window.location = '/';
app.session.delete(callback);
```

In app.session.delete:

```
app.session.delete = function(callback) {
    // do stuff
   if(callback) {
       callback();
   }
}
```